# justGage.js loading data with AJAX call and MySQL

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm a little bit new with justGage.js and I would like to load some data from MySQL. this is my gage code:

```
    var g3 = new JustGage({
                    id: "g3",
                    value: 0,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 1000,
                    title: "Scripts Started Today",
                    label: "",
                    levelColors: ['#1ab394'],
                    levelColorsGradient: false
                });
```

...and the AJAX call is this:

```
      (function updateScripts() {
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: '@Url.Action("GetQueryResult")',
         context: document.body,
         data: {
             querySetName: 'dashboard-script-statistics',
             queryName: 'NumOfStartedScript'
         },
         success: function (serveData) {
             serveData = JSON.parse(serveData);
             if (serveData.Success) {
                 $("#stat-7-value").html(serveData.Result.NUM_SCRIPT_STARTED_TODAY);
                 g3.refresh(serveData.Result.NUM_SCRIPT_STARTED_TODAY);

             } else {
                 $("#stat-7-value").prop(serveData.ErrorMessage);
             }
         },
         error: function (xhr) {
             $("#stat-7-value").attr('title', 'Error Status: ' + err.status);
         },
         complete: function () {
             setTimeout(updateScripts, 2000);
         }
     });
 })();
```

It's putting a 0 instead of 3. I checked the data and it's fine. But the value presented is 0.

Comment: Ahh never mind, I found the problem. I have it in a short way and wasn't presenting the data.

Comment: updateStat('dashboard-script-statistics', 'NumOfStartedScript', 7, function (result) {
                        $("#stat-7-value").html(serveData.Result.NUM_SCRIPT_STARTED_TODAY);
                        g3.refresh(serveData.Result.NUM_SCRIPT_STARTED_TODAY);
                    });